# How to get multiple photo names in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried the code below to get the names of all the images I selected, but when 'alert' I only got 1 name out of the many names I chose. I want all the names of the photos I have selected to be saved in an array

```
----------------js code-------
$('input[type=file]')[0].files[0].name;
```

```
------------html-------------------
<div class="form-group">
<label for="file">Chọn file Ảnh</label>
<input class="form-control" id="file" type="file" name="image[]" multiple="multiple"/>
<input type="submit"  value="upload" />
</div>
```

Comment: `.files[0]` would be the first ... `.files[1]` the second ... etc

Comment: I did, so now I put them in an array of elements, how do I count the number I can traverse?

Comment: `.files.length`?

Comment: length ?? Isn't that the length of an image file ?? I mean the number of images for the loop to add to the array

Comment: yes, my bad, you know better

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = $('input[type=file]')[0].files;
let imageNames = [];
if(images && images.length) {
 imageNames = images.map(image => image.name);    
}
console.log('All Images', imageNames);
```

You can try above solution...

You are using only first image from the array, that's why you are getting only one/first image every time.

Comment: with your command can I get the size, the path and the file type?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO. you may need to update the question/description as its vague. here is a small snippet to print all the attriutes of uploaded files as you requested.

```js
function printFiles() {
  let dt = $('input[type=file]')[0].files;
  for (let i = 0; i < dt.length; i++) {
    console.log('file Name: ' + dt[i].name + ', file size: ' + dt[i].size + ', file type: ' + dt[i].type + ', last Modified: ' + dt[i].lastModified +
      ', last ModifiedDate: ' + dt[i].lastModifiedDate);
    console.log('-----------------------------------------');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="file">Chọn file Ảnh</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="file" type="file" name="image[]" multiple="multiple" />
  <input type="submit" value="upload" onclick="printFiles()" />
</div>
```